# How to turn on red light (digital audio) inside of the 3.5mm headphone socket on macbook pros?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hardware, headphones

So apparently many macbook pro models have a digital audio output hidden inside their 3.5mm headphone jacks.  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89IJu.jpg).

I thought this was physically activated by the mini TOSLINK plug, but recently I installed Linux Mint (native boot) on my MBP and that red light came on and stay on.

So I guess it can be controlled by software.

Anyone know how to activate it in macosx?   The only reason I want to turn it on is I think it looks cool.

Comment: I could imagine you can activate digital out in [soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower)

Comment: There was a common issue with hardware on MacBook Pros where the switch would fail and leave the light on permenantly. Do the headphones work at all in macOS?

Answer (score 2):

Plug in a clear audio jack and you’ll have your red laser engaged and the sound muted. It’s controlled by firmware which is software, just harder to patch and mess with.

Answer (score -2):

Blow into the audio port with canned air or similar to remove any dust collected there.

Comment: This may need some more explanation on the effect and why this solves the problem described in the question.